# SQLAlchemy Query with Inner Join with Duplicate Column Values Criteria / Filter

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an SQLite3 database of files in which each row contains a size value and an SHA256 value.

The following SQL query finds duplicate files by returning all rows which have duplicates in both the Size and SHA256_1024 column entries.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM Files A
INNER JOIN (SELECT Size, SHA256_1024
    FROM Files
    GROUP BY Size, SHA256_1024
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)p B
ON A.Size = B.Size AND A.SHA256_1024 = B.SHA256_1024
```

And the following counts the number of duplicate files:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT A.*
FROM Files A
INNER JOIN (SELECT Size, SHA256_1024
    FROM Files
    GROUP BY Size, SHA256_1024
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) B
ON A.Size = B.Size AND A.SHA256_1024 = B.SHA256_1024) x
```

I am finding it difficult to implement the inner join and duplicate detection functionality in SQLAlchemy and I've read the documentation for Query().  There are many examples in the documentation for filtering on a value, but I don't find any showing how to compare the column values Size and SHA256_1024 for duplicate values as done in the SQL form.

```
class FO(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Files'
    Id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    File = Column(String())
    Size = Column(Integer)
    MD5_1024 = Column(String())

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///FileRel.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

session.query(FO) #??? Lots more needed:  .join .having, etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create subquery

```
from sqlalchemy import func, and_

B = session.query(FO.Size, FO.MD5_1024).group_by(FO.Size, FO.MD5_1024).having(func.count() > 1).subquery()
```

then join it

```
query = session.query(FO).join(B, and_(FO.Size == B.c.Size, FO.MD5_1024 == B.c.MD5_1024))
```

and get count

```
query.count()
```